# Using Url Query's to define page

Tags: php, get, content-management-system

The web page i want to go to is 
https://example.com/portal/projects.php?action=projectdetails&id=18

I have a file called projects.php that looks for variables and includes the correct page (projectsm projectdetails, projectedit...) But i don't know how to make the script detect if there is a page definition (`?action=projectdetails`) The `&id` variable tells to server what id to query on the database to retrieve information.

Here is my current code (which doesn't work)

```
    <?php 
session_start();
ob_start();
$currentPage = 'usrprojects';

require ('assets/config.inc.php');


if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) != true) {
header("location: login.php"); 
}
else {
    if (isset($_GET['action'])){
if( isset($_GET['projectdetails']) && $_GET['projectdetails'] == "")
{
echo "asd";
}
    }
    else {
    require 'includes/pages/projects.php';
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: when you say "it doesn't work" - in what way does it fail? I'd also suggest some sort of whitelist system with possible user access level check too perhaps

Comment: i don't the projectdetails part in the url to be a variable but a page definition. When i do isset it doesn't find it.

Comment: in the code above there is no GET variable `projectdetails` - that is the value assigned to `action`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the above would more likely be like this as you are trying to find if a GET variable is equal to `projectdetails` rather than find a GET variable with the name `projectdetails`

```
session_start();
ob_start();
$currentPage = 'usrprojects';

require ('assets/config.inc.php');


if ( isset( $_SESSION['logged_in'] ) != true ) {
    header( 'location: login.php' ); 
} else {
    if ( isset( $_GET['action'] ) ){
        if( $_GET['action'] == 'projectdetails' ) require 'includes/pages/projects.php';
        else echo 'asd';
    }
}
```

However, as I mentioned in the comment you might want to use a whitelist idea - rough idea like this:

```
session_start();
ob_start();

if( empty( $_SESSION['logged_in'] ) ){
    exit( header( 'location: login.php' ) );
}

$whitelist=array(
    'projects'  =>  array('script'=>'includes/pages/projects.php','level'=>3),
    'admin'     =>  array('script'=>'includes/pages/admin.php','level'=>1),
    'other'     =>  array('script'=>'includes/pages/other.php','level'=>5)
);

$currentPage = 'usrprojects';
require ('assets/config.inc.php');



if( !empty( $_GET['action'] ) && array_key_exists( $_GET['action'], $whitelist ) ){

    $action = $whitelist[ $_GET['action'] ]['script'];
    $level  = $whitelist[ $_GET['action'] ]['level'];

    if( file_exists( $action ) && $_SESSION['level'] <= $level ) require $action;
}
```